# How to give the option to run a programme again

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

How would I create a loop so that the programme gives the option for the user to run it again if they wanted it to?
The option could look like: "To run the programme again enter 'y', to exit enter 'n'"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this code snippet should do the work.

```
Sub Main()
    Dim retry As String
    Dim boolRetry As Boolean
    Do
        Console.WriteLine("Do something")
        'Your processes should be here...

        Do
            Console.WriteLine("To run the programme again enter 'y', to exit enter 'n'")
            retry = Console.ReadLine()
            boolRetry = IIf(retry = "y", True, False)
        Loop While (retry <> "y" And retry <> "n")
    Loop While (boolRetry)
End Sub
```

Other kinds of loop can also be used, but I prefer to use Do Loop in here.